# Is numpy matrix multiplication same as Linear Algebra matrix multiplication?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

As we know that In Linear Algebra it is mandatory to multiply a vector by matrix or multiply two matrices, the number of rows of one matrix or vector must be equal to the number of columns in other vector or matrix.

while i was working in `numpy` python and it is giving me a different result.

Here is my code and it works.

```
np.array([1,2]) * np.array([[1],[2],[3]])
```

> so is there any difference between `numpy` vector to matrix
> matlication vs linear algebra vector to matrix multiplication.

Comment: `*` is element-wise multiplication. In this case, you implicitly uses numpy's [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html). Linear Algebra's matrix multiplication would be `a @ b` or `a.dot(b)`.

Answer (score 1):

use numpy [np.dot(a,b)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)

Use the following code and you will get error you want.

```
np.dot(np.array([1,2]) ,  np.array([[1],[2],[3]]))
```

Becuase `*,+,-,/` works element-wise on arrays.

> If either a or b is 0-D (scalar), it is equivalent to multiply and
> using numpy.multiply(a, b) or a * b is preferred.